# DotNetZip - create zip from accessed file

Tags: dotnetzip

it is possible to use DotNetZip to create a zip from an accessed file (eg log file from another application) ?

so create a zip when the log file gets written through the other application

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, well, yes, if you are willing to write some code.

One way to do it is to compress the file AFTER it has been written and closed. 
You would need to have an app that runs with [a filesystem watcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx), and when it sees the log file being closed, it compresses that log file into a zip.

If you mean to imply, a distinct app that writes to a file and it automagically writes into a zip file, no I don't know of a simple way to do that.  There is one possibility: if the 3rd party app accepts a System.IO.Stream in which to write the log entries. In that case, you can do that with DotNetZip. You can get a writeable stream from DotNetZip, into which the app writes content. It is compressed as it is written, and when the writing is complete, DotNetZip closes the zipfile.  To use this, check the ZipFile.AddEntry() method that accepts a WriteDelegate.  It's in the documentation.